# Open Reports(oreports) MYSQL JDBC Connection

Tags: java, mysql

I have copied the JDC connector mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin to C:\openreports-tomcat\tomcat\common\lib and am still receiving:

```
 error.testing.connection: Cannot load JDBC driver class mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin
```

Help appreciated...

Comment: Post your code here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to load a class named `mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin`.  This is not the name of the class, it's the name of the JAR file that contains the class.

The name of the MySQL JDBC driver class is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.